# anthill and gradle plugin?

Tags: ant, gradle, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, anthill

My team currently still uses Ant for all the projects, and I am planning to migrate them over to Gradle. Unfortunately the company uses Anthill to manage build and deploy, and that's not something that can be changed. Is there any plugin or tool that may allow Anthill to play ball with Gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't need it any more.
Basically I will just have them run gradle from the command line.